# Error with MySql while doing Bundle Install

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When I do Bundle Install, I get following error:

```
Installing mysql2 (0.3.10) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/manish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/manish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
--with-mysql-config
--without-mysql-config
extconf.rb:33:in ``': No such file or directory - /usr/local/bin/mysql_config --cflags    (Errno::ENOENT)
from extconf.rb:33:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2- 0.3.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-  0.3.10/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing mysql2 (0.3.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

In the Gemfile MySql is something like this:

```
gem "mysql2", ">=0.3.0"
```

And when I also try to install MySql using brew followed with sudo it gives following error:

```
 sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/brew: Permission denied
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my solution and here it is:

Step 1: Clean Up your previously installed rvm and Xcode

```
    => rm -rf ~/.rvm    
    => sudo rm -rf /Developer
```

Step 2: Install Xcode from App Store or the installer might be saved in your Launchpad.

Step 3: Install HomeBrew:

```
    => mkdir -p /usr/local/Cellar
    => /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
```

Step 4: Install RVM

```
    => bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
    => echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" #  Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Step 5: Install Ruby 1.9.2

```
    => rvm install 1.9.2
    => rvm use ruby-1.9.2 --default
    => gem install rails thin bundler
    => rvm install 1.9.2-head
    => brew install git ack wget curl redis memcached libmemcached colordiff imagemagick
```

Step 6: Install MySql

```
    => brew install mysql
    => mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
    => mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
    => cp /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.15/com.mysql.mysqld.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
    => launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
    => mysql -u root
    => UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
    => FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: I marked it but as you know to mark your answer for own question takes two days. Anyways thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the libraries and pass in their location manually to the gem building process as flags, but that's a bit of a pain.

MySQL was being search for in /usr/local/bin which makes sense for a homebrew install but if sudo brew doesn't work, there's a permissions problem and you're likely to have far more trouble coming.

I'd fix brew honestly b/c that will continue to frustrate you. Normal dance to fix -- repair permissions using Disk Utitlity, run brew doctor to check for problems, implode and reinstall if things get bad.

Good luck